# Opening a Shared Library

Tags: python, c

I made a Shared Library for Python (.PYD). Nothing is wrong with the file but when I import it from my start.py nothing happens. No errors, nothing. Is there anyway to call a class without rewriting the entire code of the file? Or is there a way to call a class that imports the file? There isn't a class inside base.py.

Start.py

```
import dw.base
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call a class"?

Comment: @duskwuff If I put something like class Start(): inside the main module within the pyd and then some code it will work. I also will have to put `import Python` (my pyd) then after that `Start()` in start.py. It won't import anything within the start class.